# Add spaces between words in a camelCased string then uppercase the first word

Tags: php, string, uppercase, lowercase, title-case

I have two types of strings, `hello` and `helloThere`.

What I want is to change them so they read like: `Hello` and `Hello There` depending on the case.

What would be a good way of doing this?

Comment: i suppose you have a dictionary for determining where the compound words will split?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ucwords` like everyone said... to add the space in `helloThere` you can do `$with_space = preg_replace('/[A-Z]/'," $0",$string);` then `ucwords($with_space);`

Answer (score 7):

To convert CamelCase to different words:

```
preg_replace('/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/', "$1 $2", $string)
```

To uppercase all the words first letters:

```
ucwords()
```

So together:

```
ucwords(preg_replace('/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/', "$1 $2", $string))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`ucwords`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) function:

> Returns a string with the first
>   character of each word in str
>   capitalized, if that character is
>   alphabetic.
>
> The definition of a word is any string
>   of characters that is immediately
>   after a whitespace (These are: space,
>   form-feed, newline, carriage return,
>   horizontal tab, and vertical tab).

This will not split up words that are slammed together - you will have to add spaces to the string as needed for this function to work.

Comment: he needs to add the space first with `helloThere`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `ucwords` function:

```
echo ucwords('hello world');
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has many string manipulation functions. `ucfirst()` would do it for you.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

Comment: No, that function can not change CamelCase to Camel Case

Answer (score 1):

use ucwords

```
<?php
$foo = 'hello world';
$foo = ucwords($foo);             // Hello world

$bar = 'BONJOUR TOUT LE MONDE!';
$bar = ucwords($bar);             // HELLO WORLD
$bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar)); // Hello World
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make shure it works on other languages, the UTF-8 might be a good idea to implement. Im using this water proof for any languages in my wordpress installs.

```
$str = mb_ucfirst($str, 'UTF-8', true);
```

This make first letter uppercase and all other lowercase. If the third arg is set to false (default), the rest of the string is not manipulated. However, someone here might suggest an argument to re-use the function itself and mb uppercase each word after the first one, to be a more exact answer to the question.

```
// Extends PHP
if (!function_exists('mb_ucfirst')) {

function mb_ucfirst($str, $encoding = "UTF-8", $lower_str_end = false) {
    $first_letter = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, 1, $encoding), $encoding);
    $str_end = "";
    if ($lower_str_end) {
        $str_end = mb_strtolower(mb_substr($str, 1, mb_strlen($str, $encoding), $encoding), $encoding);
    } else {
        $str_end = mb_substr($str, 1, mb_strlen($str, $encoding), $encoding);
    }
    $str = $first_letter . $str_end;
    return $str;
}

}
```

/ Lundman

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to capture any letters to inject the space between words -- a lookahead will do nicely. Then apply a multibyte-safe title-case function after adding the spaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N3jDr))

```
echo mb_convert_case(
         preg_replace('~(?=\p{Lu})~u', ' ','helloThere'),
         MB_CASE_TITLE
     );
// Hello There
```